# Using Query Builder in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use Query Builder in Symfony2 to get some records from a database. I run the normal query in SQL and it returns the correct results. The query is

```
SELECT pg.name, pg.description
FROM pm_patentgroups pg
LEFT JOIN pm_portfolios pp ON pp.id = pg.portfolio_id
```

I want to use the exact query using Doctorine query builder in Symfony2. What I have tried so far is

```
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('pg')
        ->from('pm_patentgroups', 'pg')
        ->leftJoin('pg','pm_portfolios','pp','pp.id = pg.portfolio_id')
        ->getQuery();
        $portfolio_groups = $query->getResult();
```

but its giving me the following error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder()

I am new to Symfony2 and Doctorine. Can you please tell me what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the alias when using createQueryBuilder.  Since you have the repository you can drop the from portion and just use

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('pg')
```

Comment: Its giving me syntax error but not showing any specific line where the error occurs

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->addSelect('pm_patentgroups');
$qb->addSelect('pm_portfolios');

$qb->from('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups','pm_patentgroups');
$qb->leftJoin('pm_patentgroups.pm_portfolios','pm_portfolios');
```

This assumes you have your two entities properly related.

Lots of examples in the D2 manual.  Just keep in mind that query builder works with objects, not sql.

And by the way, your error message comes from the fact that the entity repository (as opposed to the entity manager) requires an alias.

Comment: I have to include where clause for the specific columns on which I want join to work?

Comment: Nope.  Once you have the relations set in your entities the query builder is smart enough to figure out the join details.  One of the nice things about qb.If you still have trouble getting the above query to work then post the relevant portions of your entities.

Comment: it is now giving me an error of undefinded method... Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::createQueryBuilder()

Comment: Should be $this->getDoctrine->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

Comment: Can I save this whole result that i get from query into an array ?

Comment: If i get the name and description in this query how i will use it in my view ?

Comment: I think I'll just bow out on this one before my sarcasm gets the better of me.